# TikZ: Problem with relative node positions for "big" nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, relative

I want to place two nodes besides each other, using TikZs `right of=` placement. But if the first node is two broad, like in the minimum example below, this does not work right. How can I make TikZ recognize the correct placement for the second node?

**EXAMPLE:**

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [] (a) {AAAAAAAAAAAA};
    \node [right of=a] (b) {B};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**OUTPUT:**
[image]

Thank you very much.

Comment: Load the `positioning` library and say `right=of `. If necessary, you can say e.g. `right-=of node.east` or `right=5mm of node` or whatever.